# 'Like' page on facebook

Tags: php, javascript, html

I want to make a business page on Facebook. Page precursor to impose on people before they enter LIKE page. And they can not see what's on the page before doing LIKE.

Comment: Well that depends how your frame your logic,simple logic would to be check if the user(with FB account) has liked your page using Facebook php sdk ,based on which displaying a popup window to user to like the page or directing the user to your Business page.

Comment: Hi there. This question is very broad, and probably needs some research and detail before it can be asked here. Can you show us some code? This question will probably close, but don't worry - it can be reopened if you edit it into the right shape.

Answer (score 2):

You should not force liking your page. It should be also against the Facebook rules actually.
Anyway you can use a plugin like this one:

http://codecanyon.net/item/facebook-traffic-pop/142429?sso?WT.ac=search_item&WT.seg_1=search_item&WT.z_author=TylerQuinn

This is a commercial one but just google your query and you will find a lot of results.

Comment: Agreed. I've heard of companies taking complaints via their FB page, such that one has to 'like' them before being able to contact them!